# How to use build-in tag "comments" in Django for custom form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I had created a comment app with custom field like "parentId" and "email_notification".
In the template, the `comments` tag can pull out items I add, but the "get_comment_form" tag does not show a form. Also, how do I customize the fields in that form?

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

class CommentWithParent(Comment):
    parentId = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    email_notification = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm
from mblog.my_comment.models import CommentWithParent
from django.db import models


class CommentWithParentForm(CommentForm):

    parentId = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    email_notification = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def get_comment_model(self):
        return CommentWithParent

    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        data = super(CommentWithParentForm, self).get_comment_create_data()
        return data

    def get_form(self):
        return self
```

*template file*

```
{% load comments %}
{% get_comment_form for entry as form %}
```

Comment: Zhuo, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question in an attempt to make it clearer. I hope I have correctly understood what you were trying to ask. If not, you should be able to re-edit or roll back my edit by clicking the time next to the "Edited by" sentence.

Comment: thank you, well, English is not my mother-tongue :)

Comment: That's OK: you're doing much better than I would in any language other than English. We're here to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can learn more about customizing the form template in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template). In general terms, you can hide some fields from the form or control which form widgets are used to display them. To change how they look, you'll want to use the application's CSS, or create a new template as the documentation describes.

I'm not entirely sure why the `get_comment_form` tag isn't working for you. The documentation linked above suggests you need a form in your view which the template can then render using a different tag; [here's that section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) of the documentation. If you're not using Django 1.4, things might be slightly different.